# Is it a bad practice to subscribe to an event with an Action

Tags: c#, event-programming, third-party-libraries

I use a third party library for speech recognition.

This library give me access to some classes ( SpeechRecognitionEngine, SpeechRecognitionConfiguration etc) which give me access to some events (OnSpeechRecognized, OnSpeechRecognitionStarted etc).

So as I could want to reuse this library any day, I created a project dedicated to handle it and give me access to only what I want.

My custom project main class has an instance of this third party engine :

```
private ThirdPartyASREngineControl _engine;
```

Which gives me access to the event RecognitionStarting this way within my custom project:

```
  _engine.RecognitionStarting += /*SOME BEHAVIOUR*/
```

The signature of RecognitionStarting and _ThirdPartyEngineControlEvents_RecognitionStartingEventHandler are :

```
event _ThirdPartyEngineControlEvents_RecognitionStartingEventHandler RecognitionStarting;

public delegate void _ThirdPartyEngineControlEvents_RecognitionStartingEventHandler();
```

Now my concern is that I want to be able to replace this **some behaviour** with anything I want in any projects using MySpeechRecognitionWrapperProject.

Here is what I've come with so far :

```
using ThirdPartyASR;
using System;
namespace MySpeechRecognitionWrapperProject
{
    public class MyWonderfulMainClass
    {

        private _ThirdPartyEngineControlEvents_RecognitionStartingEventHandler _recognitionStartedAction;
        public Action RecognitionStartedAction
        {
            set
            {
                if (_recognitionStartedAction != null)
                {
                    _engine.RecognitionStarting -= _recognitionStartedAction; // i don't believe this will work
                }
                _recognitionStartedAction =()=> value();
                _engine.RecognitionStarting += _recognitionStartedAction;
            }
        }

        private ThirdPartyASREngineControl _engine;

        public MyWonderfulMainClass()
        {
            _engine = new ThirdPartyASREngineControl();
            /*
             * more code
             *
             */
        }
        /*
         * even more code
         *
         */
    }
}
```

As you can see my goal here is that I can set any void behaviour that I want from any project using MySpeechRecognitionWrapperProject.

As someone with great difficulties wrapping my head around the event system in C#, I'm almost certain that what I'm doing is far from the neatest solution one would come with in this situation.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Except for the lambdas this doesn't look all that different from any other event subscriber code I've seen.

Comment: As far as i know you cannot unsubscribe from an event when using lambda expressions, _engine.RecognitionStarting -= () => _recognitionStartedAction() is a different lambda expression even if they call the same function

Comment: I agree with you. I edited the question with a better solution. Thanks !

Comment: @Dtex You *can* unsub a lambda, but you have to hold onto a reference to the lambda to do so.  Creating a new lambda, even if it has the same code, isn't going to be equal.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. An EventHandler has caller and event parameters which an Action has not.

Why not expose an `EventHandler<T>` or at least an `Action<T>`

By using Actions you are reimplementing the EventHandler system

Comment: In this situtation i cannot use an EventHandler as my event RecognitionStarting is of type  _ThirdPartyEngineControlEvents_RecognitionStartingEventHandler which is basically an Action as it is a delegate void foo();

Comment: if you are hiding the underlying implementation the type could be mapped

Comment: I don't get it. Could you please give me an example ?